# generating random numbers in java and finding percentage of how many are less than or equal to 50

Tags: java

My question is why isn't the code generating the amount of numbers that the users enters? Right now the code is only generating one number. Here is the original question given to me:

> "In your main method, prompt the user for a number n. Write a method
>   called `assessRandomness` that generates a random number between 1 and
>   100 'n' times and return the percentage of times the number was less than
>   or equal to 50. Call your `assessRandomness` method from `main` and display
>   the result to the user from `main`. Do not interact with the user from
>   within the `assessRandomness` method."

output:

```
 How many random numbers should I generate? 10
 <assume the random numbers generated were 11 7 50 61 52 3 92 100 81 66>
 40% of the numbers were 50 or less
```

my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("how many random numbers should I generate?: ");
    int number = in.nextInt();
    assessRandomness(number);
}

public static double assessRandomness(int n){
    int random = (int)(Math.random()*100);
    int randomNumbersLessthan50 = 0;

    if (random <= 50)
    {
        double getPercentage = random/randomNumbersLessthan50; 
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(random);
    }

    return random;
}
```

Comment: Well, why do you think this code should generate n random numbers? Where does it use n? Does it have a loop?

Comment: You need a `for` loop to run the code `n` times, each time it generates a new random, and if it is less than 50, add 1 to a counter.

Comment: Side note: you're violating the directive `Don't interact with the user from within the assessRandomness method`, you're printing to output there.  You should be returning the percentage, not one of the random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any kind of loop within `assessRandomness`.
Try

```
for(int x = 1; x <= n; x++){ ... }
```

as first line in `assessRandomness`, it should finally look like

```
public static double assessRandomness(int n){
    int counterLessThan50 = 0;
    for ( int x = 1; x <= n; x++)
        if( (int)(Math.random()*100) <= 50 ) counterLessThan50++;
    return (double) counterLessThan50 / n;
}
```

Comment: its still not working correctly, i Cant get it to output the percentage of numbers less than or equal to 50.

Comment: okay i think ive got everything except , how can i show the numbers the random number generator printed? @tilhox1

Answer (score 1):

There's no repetition in your code to do something n times.

Here's one way to do it in one line using a stream:

```
public static double assessRandomness(int n) {
    return Stream.generate(Math::random).limit(n).map(r -> r * 100 + 1).filter(r -> r <= 50).count() / (double)n;
}
```

Note that converting `Math.random()` to a number in the range 1-100 is pointless; this will give the same result:

```
public static double assessRandomness(int n) {
    return Stream.generate(Math::random).limit(n).filter(n -> n < .5).count() / (double)n;
}
```

And is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, your assessRandomness method never uses the variable n.

At first you should initialize a variable which counts the number of created randoms that are bigger than 50 (this will be your retutn value). You should then do a loop from 0 until n. For each loop run you should create a random value between 0 and 100. Then you should check wether the value is bigger than 50. If so, count up your previously created variable. When the loop has finished, return the count variable and print it in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you understand better how to do something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("how many random numbers should I generate?: ");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = in.nextInt();

    int[] arrayPlaceHolderInMainMethod = new int[number];
    arrayPlaceHolderInMainMethod = generateRandomNumberArray(number);

    assessRandomness(arrayPlaceHolderInMainMethod);
}

public static void assessRandomness(int[] inputArray) {

    int randomNumbersLessthan50 = 0;
    int randomNumbersGreaterthan50 = 0;
    int random = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        random = inputArray[i];
    }

    if (random <= 50) {
        randomNumbersLessthan50 += 1;
    } else {
        randomNumbersGreaterthan50 += 1;
    }

    System.out.println(">50: " + randomNumbersGreaterthan50 + " Less: " + randomNumbersLessthan50);
}

public static int[] generateRandomNumberArray(int numberPickedByUser) {
    int[] arrayOfRandomNumbers = new int[numberPickedByUser];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberPickedByUser; i++) {
        arrayOfRandomNumbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    }

    return arrayOfRandomNumbers;
}
```